# Валидация теста с radio кнопками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form, валидация

Как сделать правильно валидацию на отмечание да/нет, чтобы если пользователь не отметил один из вариантов ему это сообщило. Разметку страницы можно для правильности изменить. Так же вопросов может быть сколько угодно.

```html
<form action="" name="question_form">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row page_title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row question_q">
        <div class="questions">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <p>Question-1?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="radio1" />
                    <label for="radio1">yes</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question1" id="radio2" />
                    <label for="radio2">no</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <p>Question-2?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" id="radio3"/>
                    <label for="radio3">yes</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question2" id="radio4" />
                    <label for="radio4">no</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="questions">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
                <p>Question-3?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" id="radio5"/>
                    <label for="radio5">yes</label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="radio" name="question3" id="radio6" />
                    <label for="radio6">no</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-8 col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 col-xs-12">
            <input type="submit" id="complete" value="go">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отмечайте обязательные радиокнопки атрибутом `required`

```html
<form action="" name="question_form">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row page_title">
      <h1>Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row question_q">
      <div class="questions">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <p>Question-1?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="radio1" required />
            <label for="radio1">yes</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question1" id="radio2" required />
            <label for="radio2">no</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="questions">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <p>Question-2?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="radio3" require d/>
            <label for="radio3">yes</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question2" id="radio4" required />
            <label for="radio4">no</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="questions">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
          <p>Question-3?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 radio_btn">
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question3" id="radio5" required />
            <label for="radio5">yes</label>
          </div>
          <div>
            <input type="radio" name="question3" id="radio6" required />
            <label for="radio6">no</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-8 col-md-4 col-md-offset-8 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-8 col-xs-12">
          <input type="submit" id="complete" value="go">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```